# Bring field content from "parent" node to "child" node in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, field

What I need to do is bring data from a field in a "parent" node to a "child" node. Something like the following:

```
$myactive_trail = menu_get_active_trail();
$parent = $myactive_trail['2']['link_path'];
print $parent->field_video['0']['filepath'];
```

I know that there is not such thing as a parent not hence me trying to use `menu_get_active_trail()`. I can print the `$parent` `link_path`, but don't know how to call up a field from the parent node.

Comment: is the `}` in `$myactive_trail['2'}['link_path'];` a typo?

Comment: How are you build parent -> child nodes? if you use books module, there's already own function for this. If you use nodereference of cck it more simpler...

Comment: the nodes are pages. I installed nodereference but I have no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in a similar position. CCK Node references are quite useful, and actually rather simple once you know how to manipulate them. If I understand your question correctly... I believe you want to add parts of the "parent" node type when you display the "child" node type. If that's right, there is a tutorial video that explains how to do EXACTLY that. It also gives pointers on actually setting up a CCK node reference.

http://geoffhankerson.com/drupal/cck-nodereference-screencast.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: I felt the exact same way when I found it :)